# Option Value "-" gives empty string (HTML PHP)

Tags: php, html, string

I am trying to POST select values from my HTML form into my Database with phpmysqli.
Somehow the value "-" results as an empty string. The other values are perfectly fine.
So echo `$title` with value `"-" = ""` ; with value `"Dr." = "Dr."`

**My HTML:**

```
<select
                  name="title"
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width: 50%;"
                  required
                >
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Titula</option>
                  <option value="-">-</option>
                  <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                  <option value="Prof. Dr.">Prof. Dr.</option>
                </select>
```

**My PHP:**

```
    <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = PASSWORD_HASH($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$title = $_POST['title'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$father = $_POST['father'];
$mother = $_POST['mother'];

if (!empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($birth) || !empty($title) || !empty($mail) || !empty($phone) || !empty($fname) || !empty($lname) || !empty($street) || !empty($city) || !empty($country) || !empty($zip) || !empty($father) || !empty($mother)) {
 $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "";
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8mb4');
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $SELECT = "SELECT mail From users Where mail = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into users (username, password, birth, title, mail, phone, fname, lname, street, city, country, zip, father, mother) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $mail);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($mail);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss", $username, $password, $birth, $title, $mail, $phone, $fname, $lname, $street, $city, $country, $zip, $father, $mother);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
      echo $title; //empty string
      //header('Location: login.html');
     } else {
      echo "Someone already register using this email";
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All field are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: From this code (and in general), I don't know how that could be happening. Unless you have some sort of javascript overhead which is pre-attacking your form data on submit (which is not shown here).

Comment: where have you tried to fill the session variables. By your code, It shows that you are moving session variable values to php variables.